# Number Pad in ASP.NET webpage

Tags: asp.net, onclick, onblur

I am trying to get a number pad to work on a webpage. The application is to be deployed for some touchscreen devices. The application will reuquire user to just punch in numbers. Now my theory at the beginning was to store the id of the textbox that loses focus and save it in a variable. Then at the click event, of any of the buttons of the number pad, append the caracter represented by the button to the textbox which loses the focus due to the clic on the button.

I have tried this so far:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Textbox" onblur="losesfocus(this)"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Npad7"  runat="server" Text="7" CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick="DpadDown(7); return false"></asp:Button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var ControlID=""
 function losesfocus(ObjId)
{
   ControlID = ObjId.value
}
function NpadDown(KeyVal)
{
    var len= parseInt(ControlID.value.length);
    var lenmax= parseInt(ControlID.getAttribute("MaxLength"));
    if (len< lenmax)
         {
             document.getElementById(ControlID).text = document.getElementById(ControlID).text + KeyVal;
         }
}
```

Look I am noob at web programming so I am sure this code it may not be close to working (obviously it does not, if it did I wouldn't be posting the question) nor have good practices for coding. Anyway. I need something to help me with the losing focus of the textbox and the appending of the character to the textbox. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? (I suggested a win app and not a web app, but they wanted a web app anyway :S)